# If it's worth answering, it's worth upvoting

Tags: discussion

Yes or no?  I would argue that most of the time, one should vote up the question if you're answering it. I'd like to see more people taking the half-a-second to upvote a question, after they've clearly spent tens or hundreds or times as long answering the question.  Once you've answered a question, you've presumably also spent the time understanding and measuring the validity of the question, so I would have thought this would tend to encourage an upvote.

There is also an element of self-interest, if you're interested in scoring reputation points.  Voting up questions [apparently adds to "hotness"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6792/upvoting-of-a-question-should-bump-it-to-the-front-page), and if questions are listed by votes, and there are more of them, your answer is likely to be seen and up-voted as well.

Here's a relevant discussion (I'm sure there are others), from meta.stackoverflow: [Why Aren't People Voting for Questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/why-arent-people-voting-for-questions)

Answer (score 12):

I typically upvote if:

- it's a good question
- the person has added detail that someone else can answer it, even if I can't, because a good question is a contribution to the site.

Comment: I pretty much assume whatever Jorge Castro does is the correct way to do things, so I'm glad you put in your view.  [This is actually what I tend to do as well (though I up-vote things I answer >90% of the time, I think).]

Answer (score 9):

I'm a bit more stingy with my votes on questions. I'll vote for something if:

- It's a genuinely good and interesting question.
- I think it deserves more attention.
- I think people have unfairly voted against it.

But I wouldn't vote for something just because I understood it well enough to answer it. Mediocre questions can often be answered too.

Comment: Mediocre questions usually get mediocre answers, but yes, if you're someone who gives good answers to mediocre questions (through telepathy, stubbornness, Ubuntu-love, point-whoring, boundless altruism, etc.), I take your point.  That's definitely reasonable.

Comment: I don't just mean the physical quality, answerability, etc, I mean subject matter too. I vote for questions that interest me. I don't think it would be right that everybody just vote for questions that are technically adept (though that's their choice).